# How can I duplicate files and folders without content?

Tags: bash

So here's the situation: I need to make a copy of a file servers folders and files, but I only care about the names, not the actual file content, so to avoid copying terabytes-worth of data, I just want to create 0-byte files in folders on another volume like so:

```
/vol1/folder1/file1.mov (3.2 GB) -> /vol2/folder1/file1.mov (0 B)
/vol1/folder2/file3.txt (0.2 KB) -> /vol2/folder2/file3.txt (0 B)
```

etc.

I was able to get part way there by piping the output of `find /vol1/` to `touch` but this approach doesn't handle folders correctly.

I'm using a Mac, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are only directories and regular files, you can do something like this:

```
cd "$src"
find . -type d -print0 | ( cd "$dst" ; xargs -0 mkdir -p )
find . -type f -print0 | ( cd "$dst" ; xargs -0 touch )
```

Comment: What are"$src" and  "$dst"... just random variables with no explanation? Please expand your explanation.